# Runtime error on custom PaperComponent of Material UI Autocomplete

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm developing a react app.
I'm using the Materia UI Autocomplete as input to enter the address with the help of hints. Everything works fine, but I'd like customize the Autocomplete element so that it an visualize a kind of footer.

this is my PaperComponent:

```
const PaperComponent = ( children: any ) => (
        <Card>
          {children}
          <div> content </div>
        </Card>
      )
```

this is my Autocomplete:

```
<Autocomplete
            style={...}
            id="autocomplete"
            getOptionLabel={(option: string) => option}
            filterOptions={(x) => x}
            options={...}
            autoComplete
            includeInputInList
            filterSelectedOptions
            value={...}
            onChange={...}
            onInputChange={...}
            renderInput={...}
            renderOption={...}
            freeSolo
            clearOnBlur
            clearOnEscape
            PaperComponent={PaperComponent} />;
```

These are the warnings message (after these all goes bad):

```
Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children` supplied to `ForwardRef(Card)`, expected a ReactNode.
```

```
Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {className, children}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  const PaperComponent = ({ children }) => (
    <Card>
     {children}
     <div> content </div>
    </Card>
  );
```

You forgot the props destructuring. **children** should from props **props.children**